# Marcro to define a variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile

there are 6 program in the directory:

- call_api_pcie
- call_api_pcie_static
- call_api_sockrpc
- call_api_sockrpc_static
- call_api_sockraw
- call_api_sockraw_static

I want to use some flags/config to let the Makefile know which program is in the list

There will be some Flag or config to define if this feature/program is used.

```
PROG_USE_PCIE := 1
PROG_USE_SOCKRAW := 1
RROG_USE_SOCKRPC := 1
PROG_USE_STATIC := 1
```

Make a list in a variable to defines all these program if [PROG_USE_XX] is enabled

```
PROGRAM_NAME := call_api
MY_PROGRAM := nothing
```

If the config/flag [PROG_USE_XX] is enabled, add the matched program

```
#if [PROG_USE_xx] is enabled, it will be include 
ifeq [PROG_USE_STATIC==1] && [PROG_USE_PCIE==1] 
    MY_PROGRAM += call_api_pcie_static
endif 
ifeq [PROG_USE_STATIC==1] && [PROG_USE_SOCKRAW==1]
    MY_PROGRAM += call_api_sockraw_static
endif
ifeq [PROG_USE_STATIC==1] && [PROG_USE_SOCKRPC==1]
    MY_PROGRAM += call_api_sockrpc_static
endif
ifeq [PROG_USE_PCIE==1]
    MY_PROGRAM += call_api_pcie
endif
ifeq [PROG_USE_SOCKRPC==1]
    MY_PROGRAM += call_api_sockrpc
endif
ifeq [PROG_USE_SOCKRAW==1]
    MY_PROGRAM += call_api_sockraw
endif
```

Is there any easy way to define these flag and list ?

when it comes to "install" section in Makefile

```
pushd ${BUILD_DIR} && cp -f ${MY_PROGRAM} ${dest_dir} && popd
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do it this way:

```
PROGS := pcie sockraw sockrpc
PROG_USE_STATIC := 1

PROGRAM_NAME := call_api
MY_PROGRAM := #nothing                                                                                                                                   

PROGS := $(addprefix $(PROGRAM_NAME)_, $(PROGS))

ifeq ($(PROG_USE_STATIC),1)
PROGS += $(addsuffix _static, $(PROGS))
endif

MY_PROGRAM := $(PROGS)
```

Comment: that's wonderful.  Always amazing at some flashed skills in linux shell or Makefile.  There are much thing to be learned.